# Calculating $\int \frac{x^2 - 2x + 3}{x^4 -x^2 +1}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was calculating

$$\int \frac{x^7 + 3x^6 - x^4 + 6x^3 -1}{x^4 - x^2 + 1}dx$$

I performed Euclidean division and the integral reduced to

$$\frac{x^4}4 + x^3 + \frac{x^2}2 + 2x + \frac32 \ln(x^4 - x^2 + 1) - J(x)$$

with

$$J(x) = \int \frac{x^2 - 2x +3}{x^4 - x^2 + 1}dx$$

How to calculate $J(x)$?

My try:

$$J(x) = \int \frac{x^2 + 3}{x^4 - x^2 + 1}dx - \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt 3} \right)$$

Now I am stuck

Comment: Are you interested in the general primitive or just in the integral over some interval? In the second case, things may be considerably easier.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am interested in the general primitive

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio but I don't see how things can be considerably easier in that case. If you have a nice trick please share it.

Comment: You can factorize the $x^4-x^2+1$ further and use partial fraction.

Comment: @QingZhang but is there a way to do it without having to work with complex numbers?

Comment: any irreducible polynomial over $\textbf{R}$ is either degree 1 or degree 2.

Comment: @QingZhang oh I see, but I don't know how to do a partial fraction decomposition in this case.

Comment: @QingZhange perhaps you can't give a hint or something?

Comment: ha, I can't. Anyway, this is not my homework.

Comment: whatever. If you have trouble to factorize a degree 4 polynomial, probably this problem is not for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator readily factors into $$x^4 - x^2 + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt{3}x + 1)(x^2 - \sqrt{3}x + 1),$$ where upon the usual partial fraction decomposition procedure requires us to solve $$x^2-2x+3 = (Ax + B)(x^2 - 3x+1) + (Cx + D)(x^2 + 3x + 1)$$ for suitable coefficients $A, B, C, D$.  I trust that this is something you are able to do.  It may be a bit tedious, but it is the "canonical" method of solution for the indefinite integral.

---

Perhaps a little additional motivation may be useful.

We could look at the solutions of the general quadric $f(x) = x^4 - x^2 + 1$ as the square roots of the equivalent quadratic $f(x) = g(x^2) = (x^2)^2 - (x^2) + 1$, and multiply together the pairs of linear factors corresponding to complex conjugate roots, but this is not particularly elegant in this case.  Rather, we can use a "naive" approach and presuppose that $f$ factors nicely in the form $$x^4 - x^2 + 1 = (x^2 + ax + 1)(x^2 + bx + 1).$$  Expanding the RHS and comparing the coefficients to those on the LHS, it becomes obvious that we must have $b = -a$, and $2 - a^2 = -1$.  This gives us $a = \pm \sqrt{3}$, and the aforementioned factorization follows.  This sort of trick works in simple cases such as this.

Comment: Thanks! So I take it as a rule of thumb that when the denominator has degree $n$, the numerator in partial fraction decomposition should have degree $n-1$?

Comment: @Cauchy Unfortunately, no.  In partial fraction decomposition, we generally seek to decompose into rational functions whose polynomial denominator degree is at most $2$.  However, if the denominator of the original rational function is a polynomial with a **repeated** root, the resulting decomposition will contain factors with multiplicity up to that of the multiplicity of the root.  So for example, $$\frac{x^2 + 3}{x (x+1)^2 (x-5)^3} = -\frac{3}{125 x}+\frac{1}{54 (x+1)}+\frac{1}{54 (x+1)^2}+\frac{37}{6750
   (x-5)}-\frac{37}{1350 (x-5)^2}+\frac{7}{45 (x-5)^3}.$$